# Can non-periodic discrete auto-correlation be inversed?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, convolution

I'm trying to understand whether discrete auto-correlation can be reversed.

That is, we are given $t_0, \dots, t_n \in \mathbb C$ and a set of equations

$$
t_{k} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-k} b_i b_{i+k},
$$

for which we need to figure out whether there is any $b_0,\dots,b_n \in \mathbb C$ that satisfy it.

From some experimentation with SymPy on custom values of $t_k$ and small $n$, it appears that the solution may not exist, but if it exists, there may as well be up to $2^{n+1}$ or so distinct solutions. So, the main questions are whether there is any simple criterion as to whether a solution exists at all, and more generally, is it possible to somehow describe all solutions?

The case of periodic $t_k$ and $b_i$ appeared on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818733/auto-correlation-function-an-inverse-problem) and [dsp.stackexchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49879/auto-correlation-function-an-inverse-problem). Then, there is an infinite amount of solutions that can be described in terms of DFT of $t_k$. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to help in a non-periodic case though.

**Some further thoughts**:

The problem may be formulated in terms of polynomials. Consider a Laurent polynomial
$$
T(x) = t_{n} x^{-n} + \dots + t_{1} x^{-1} + t_0 + t_1 x + \dots + t_n x^n.
$$
The set of equations above are equivalent to $T(x) = B(x) B(x^{-1})$, where

$$
B(x) = b_0 + b_1 x + \dots + b_n x^n.
$$

This formulation also explains why periodic case is much simpler, as it formulates as
$$
T(x) \equiv B(x) B(x^{-1}) \pmod{x^{n+1}-1}.
$$

Besides polynomials, we can also formulate the problem in matrix form as

$$
T = B^\top B,
$$

where

$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
b_0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & b_0 & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_n & \vdots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & b_n & \ddots & b_0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & b_n
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{(2n+1) \times n}
$$

and

$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}
t_0 & t_{1} & \cdots & t_{n} \\
t_1 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots& \ddots & t_0 & t_{1} \\
t_{n} & \cdots & t_1 & t_0 
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}.
$$

So one necessary condition is that the Toeplitz matrix $T$, defined as above, is positive-definite (because it is a Gramian matrix). I'm not sure if it is sufficient for such decomposition to exist, and even if so, how to describe all such decompositions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B(x) = \lambda_0 \prod\limits_{i=1}^n (x-\lambda_i)$. Then, we can represent $x^n T(x)$ as

$$
x^n T(x) = \lambda_0^2\prod\limits_{i=1}^n (x-\lambda_i)(1-x\lambda_i) = (-1)^n\lambda_0^2\lambda_1 \dots \lambda_n \prod\limits_{i=1}^n (x-\lambda_i)(x-\lambda_i^{-1}).
$$

For any palindromic $x^n T(x)$ of degree $2n$, if $\lambda$ is the root of $x^n T(x)$, then so is $\lambda^{-1}$.

So, knowing the factorization of $T(x)$, we can pick the "main" $\lambda_i$ in each pair, compute $\lambda_0^2$ for this choice (by dividing the leading coefficient with $\lambda_1 \dots \lambda_n$), and then find $B(x)$ as

$$
B(x) = \pm \lambda_0\prod\limits_{i=1}^n (x-\lambda_i).
$$

This also explains why computations showed up that there are at most $2^{n+1}$ solutions, as you pick one of two options for the "main" $\lambda_i$ for $n$ times, and also a sign for $\lambda_0$ once.

Comment: Now that I think of it, it strongly resembles some other facts about conjugates, such as e.g. that a polynomial $T(x) > 0$ with real coefficients can always be represented as $T(x) = |A(x)|^2$, where $A(x)$ is a polynomial with possibly complex coefficients.

Or the fact that any positive-definite matrix is also a gramian matrix (see [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)).

Comment: Oops, I guess I rather meant $T(x) = A(x) \operatorname{conj}(A)(x)$, where $\operatorname{conj}(A)$ conjugates all coefficients of $A(x)$, without conjugating powers of $x$. So, like, $T(x) = A(x) \overline{A}(\overline{x})$, I guess.